# Speed up or automate creation of history table triggers

Tags: mysql, database-design, triggers

Are there any useful tools or tricks to automatically (or quickly) create history tables + triggers for a given table in MySQL? [I've come across this tool so far](http://blog.stevehorn.cc/blog?tag=MySql), but it hasn't been updated in a while. If it's relevant, I use MySQL Workbench's "Model" tool to build my database models and then synchronize those with my local database.

What I would like is to be able to provide create scripts for tables and have the tool magically spit out create scripts for history tables and triggers to insert into those history tables on insert/update/delete. For example, if I have table `foo` with composite PK `a`, `b`, foreign keys `c`, `d`, and attributes `e`, `f`, it would produce create scripts for a history table `foo_history` with composite PK `a`, `b`, `revisionNum`, and `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`, removing relations from `c` and `d` - plus perhaps a column indicating the time of the operation and whether it was an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

I would be happy to produce such a script and share it if it does not already exist, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if it does. If it does not, what do you think would be the most convenient format for others to consume such a script / how would you fit it into your model development workflow?

Comment: Hi, how did you solve this problem?

Comment: @biziclop, I'm still undecided - I took a look at your script and it is very nice. I may still try to develop something myself, but if I do it will be a plugin for an existing modeling or management system like Workbench or PHPMyAdmin, so that it is more integrated into the experience of spec-ing out the database. Regardless, +1 for your script. I'll update this post if I ever get around to actually doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created this little monster php script for myself, which generates SQL DDLs from some shorthand txt file, and now it can generate a history table and its `CREATE TRIGGER` statements.

http://simpleddl.coolpage.biz/

Example source:

```
// ZZZ means "Create History Table + Triggers"
// you can try editing it live at the link above

!DROP
= ID id P AI

person ZZZ
  ID
  name _
  N mother_id -> person
  N father_id -> person
  !FK mother_id, father_id -> family

family ZZZ
  P female_id -> person
  P male_id   -> person
```

The resulting SQL DDLs:

```
DROP   TABLE IF     EXISTS person;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (
   id         INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   mother_id  INT NULL,
   father_id  INT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id ),
   FOREIGN KEY ( mother_id ) REFERENCES person( id ),
   FOREIGN KEY ( father_id ) REFERENCES person( id ),
   FOREIGN KEY ( mother_id, father_id ) REFERENCES family( female_id, male_id )
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

DROP   TABLE IF     EXISTS family;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS family (
   female_id  INT NOT NULL,
   male_id    INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( female_id, male_id ),
   FOREIGN KEY ( female_id ) REFERENCES person( id ),
   FOREIGN KEY ( male_id ) REFERENCES person( id )
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP   TABLE IF     EXISTS zz_person;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS zz_person (
   id         INT NOT NULL,
   name       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   mother_id  INT NULL,
   father_id  INT NULL,
   _zz_id     INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   _zz_op     CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
   _zz_date   datetime NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( _zz_id ),
   INDEX P ( id ),
   INDEX ( father_id, mother_id ),
   INDEX ( _zz_op ),
   INDEX ( _zz_date )
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

DROP   TABLE IF     EXISTS zz_family;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS zz_family (
   female_id  INT NOT NULL,
   male_id    INT NOT NULL,
   _zz_id     INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   _zz_op     CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
   _zz_date   datetime NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( _zz_id ),
   INDEX P ( male_id, female_id ),
   INDEX ( _zz_op ),
   INDEX ( _zz_date )
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


DROP   TRIGGER IF EXISTS INSERT_ON_person;
CREATE TRIGGER           INSERT_ON_person
                   AFTER INSERT ON person
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO
zz_person (     id,     name,     mother_id,     father_id, _zz_date, _zz_op )
   VALUES ( NEW.id, NEW.name, NEW.mother_id, NEW.father_id,  NOW()  ,  'i'   );

DROP   TRIGGER IF EXISTS UPDATE_ON_person;
CREATE TRIGGER           UPDATE_ON_person
                   AFTER UPDATE ON person
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO
zz_person (     id,     name,     mother_id,     father_id, _zz_date, _zz_op )
   VALUES ( NEW.id, NEW.name, NEW.mother_id, NEW.father_id,  NOW()  ,  'u'   );

DROP   TRIGGER IF EXISTS DELETE_ON_person;
CREATE TRIGGER           DELETE_ON_person
                   AFTER DELETE ON person
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO
zz_person (     id,     name,     mother_id,     father_id, _zz_date, _zz_op )
   VALUES ( OLD.id, OLD.name, OLD.mother_id, OLD.father_id,  NOW()  ,  'd'   );

DROP   TRIGGER IF EXISTS INSERT_ON_family;
CREATE TRIGGER           INSERT_ON_family
                   AFTER INSERT ON family
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO
zz_family (     female_id,     male_id, _zz_date, _zz_op )
   VALUES ( NEW.female_id, NEW.male_id,  NOW()  ,  'i'   );

DROP   TRIGGER IF EXISTS UPDATE_ON_family;
CREATE TRIGGER           UPDATE_ON_family
                   AFTER UPDATE ON family
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO
zz_family (     female_id,     male_id, _zz_date, _zz_op )
   VALUES ( NEW.female_id, NEW.male_id,  NOW()  ,  'u'   );

DROP   TRIGGER IF EXISTS DELETE_ON_family;
CREATE TRIGGER           DELETE_ON_family
                   AFTER DELETE ON family
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO
zz_family (     female_id,     male_id, _zz_date, _zz_op )
   VALUES ( OLD.female_id, OLD.male_id,  NOW()  ,  'd'   );
```

Test fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d05e6/1

Answer (score 0):

I would just write a tool to query the schema of the table and then generate the scripts to run manually.  Just a simple code generator in your favorite language.

As a note I would recommend writing scripts to remove the objects you have scripted.  Just helps clean up in case you get it wrong the first few times.